# Get last inserted event

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Following are my database table entries:

```
 id    cid     data_ref_id   event_type_id  event_handle     event_datetime

  1    235        1                162      Test description   2016-08-14
  2    235        1                162      Test1 description  2016-08-15
  3    235        1                162      Test2 description  2017-05-01
  4    235        1                162      Test3 description  2017-05-12
```

While showing event entry for 2 it should show event 1 event_datetime as past event entry. For event entry 4 it should show event 3 event_datetime as past event entry and so on...Is there any way by sql to get such record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `id` is PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY in the "entries" table, and assuming that the "previous" event_datetime is based on the `id` value (from row id=1 for row id=2,  from row id=3 for row id=4), something like this would return the event_datetime from the "previous" row...

```
SELECT e.id
     , e.event_datetime
     , ( SELECT p.event_datetime 
           FROM entries p
          WHERE p.id < e.id
          ORDER BY p.id DESC
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS prev_event_datetime
  FROM entries e
 ORDER BY e.id
```

If the "previous" `event_datetime` is based on the value of `event_datetime` rather than `id`, then the correlated subquery can use the `event_datetime` column in place of `id`.

```
SELECT e.id
     , e.event_datetime
     , ( SELECT p.event_datetime 
           FROM entries p
          WHERE p.event_datetime < e.event_datetime
          ORDER BY p.event_datetime DESC
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS prev_event_datetime
  FROM entries e
 ORDER BY e.id
```

---

Both options are presented here, because the specification isn't clear.  Do we want row id=1 as "previous" for row id=2, because that's the previous `id`... or are we getting that row because row id=1 happens to have the latest `event_datetime` that is earlier than `event_datetime` on row id=2. It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select max(t2.event_datetime)
        from t t2
        where t2.event_datetime < t.event_datetime
       ) as prev_datetime
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT event_type_id,MAX(event_datetime) FROM `table` WHERE 1;
```

This will select the last inserted event.

Comment: The value for event_type_id will be indeterminate; there is no guarantee the value will be from a row that has the maximum event_datetime. (If MySQL sql_mode for the session includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, the query will throw an error. (The `WHERE 1` clause is superfluous, since it evaluates to TRUE for every row in the table, it has no effect.)